# bitmap getPixel different color

Tags: android

I'm drawing on canvas using this color:

```
Color.rgb(110, 110, 110)
```

Next I need to check how many pixels are "painted" so I loop through bitmap using getPixel method but it returns different color. Why? This happens only if I use custom color (set rgb values), with standard colors like Color.BLUE getPixel works fine.

EDIT:

This is how I create canvas:

```
this.frameBuffer = frameBuffer;
this.canvas = new Canvas(this.frameBuffer);
```

This is how I draw circles on it:

```
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
```

I'm using frameBufffer bitmap to getPixels

```
Color.rgb(110, 110, 110)
```

and

```
Color.argb(255, 110, 110, 110)
```

returns same value = -9539986

But

```
frameBufffer.getPixel(i, j)
```

returns -9736853

Comment: how do you fill your canvas with colors, and how do you get them? Paste that parts of code so everyone can get more info. This is not very clear.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a "different" color it is returning? It might contain an alpha value

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends if you have aliasing or not no the paint color. If you have aliasing there will be color variants between your paint color and the background color on the edges on the circle.

Note: Very old question but it still lacked an answer.